# How to implement panel with features of ListBox And FlipView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm am not good enough in `WPF`, so I'd like to ask for any advice how to implement panel layout something link displayed on image below:
[image: basic layout of the panel]

So, the main purpose is to display a collection of items with possibility to select a single item, which should be moved to the first position (probably with animation) and then another item template should be applied to that container (it is bigger than other items in the collection). The list doesn't have to be infinitive, so just like a simple `ListBox`.

For me it looks like a `FlipView` but with a few items, which are neighboring siblings of the selected one and are also visible in the panel's viewport.

Please, advice me how to implement such a panel, or if you have seen something suitable, please, provide a link to the source.

Comment: We like to see people try first. A ListBox sounds about right for and perhaps right for both set of items, if I understand that. The scrolling set of items horizontally should probably be in a ScrollViewer with the scroll bars turned off.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create your custom panel using User control.
[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/393ac5/arrangement-of-items-in-list-box-using-wpf/) is one example which is similar to your requirement.